# Ubuntu Partition Got Wiped and Cannot Install Ubuntu Again

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I dual-booted Ubuntu 16.04.2 with Windows 10 recently. After a while, Ubuntu stopped booting up and was stuck on the load screen (the one with the dots).

I took this chance to install another flavour of Ubuntu, but the installation got stuck (this happened after the partitioning for the install was done) and I had to quit the installation.

Now, whenever I try to install Ubuntu again (Mate 16.04.2), the install gets stuck on finding other operating systems and gives `error, invalid access to FAT (0xXXXX..)` (secure boot and fast startup are disabled). On boot, the Grub2 screen (grub2>) appears.

Windows 10 runs just fine still by pressing F12 and choosing Windows Boot Manager.

How to fix this?

Comment: do you have LVM partitions? there is/was a bug related to OS-prober and LVM

Comment: I don't know how to check if I do (I'm unaware of LVM partitions). How do I check this on Windows?

Comment: you partition information will have different identifiers. can you post the partition information?

Comment: Does this work? : http://imgur.com/KFjQ4Qo

Comment: i don't see a reason for it to not install, you only have one linux partition. and you are installing an EFI version yes?

Comment: Yes. I was installing an EFI version.

Comment: unfortunately I can only guess as to why it errors

Comment: You've got a *lot* of partitions. I recommend you delete those that you don't need (including the failed previous installations) and run filesystem checks on the rest. Also, [disable Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) in Windows. These features can cause filesystem corruption, which may be causing problems.

Comment: I solved the problem (at least for now). I ran 'chkdsk' on my EFI partition and now Ubuntu installed.

Anyway, some of those are Windows Recovery partitions and Dell partitions which were already there. Is it fine to delete those? I'm not going to use Windows much at all. Could you point me to ones safe to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. I ran a `chkdsk` on my EFI partition from Windows and it fixed the installation issue.